# How change master and detail page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a problem with good implementation with chaged navigation page with masterAndDetail. I want do something like on the photo.
[My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeA3h.png)

How can I change master or detail page and go to the next page.
This is fragment code xaml for masterPage I biinding List from ViewModel:

```xml
 <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ListView.Header>

...implementation view
```

implement xaml and class MainPage:

```xml
 <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:FishGielda.Views"
                  mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="FishGielda.MainPage">    
</MasterDetailPage>
```

```cs
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Master = new MenuPage();
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new GroupListPage());
            App.MasterDetail = this;
        }
}
```

i try something like that, but doesn't work good

```cs
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage() { Detail = new NavigationPage(new SecondPage()) });
```

how can i change master or detail page and navigation to next pages?

Comment: you want to change the master Items?

Comment: yes, this is the biggest problem than me

Comment: Maybe you can use two master details page. It is the quickest solution I think

Comment: You could change the MainPage of the app in runtime .

Comment: Is it correct set masterPage ```App.MasterDetail.Master = new NewMaster()``` ?

Comment: @TigerBonzo add everything in master details page & try to mange there visibility according to your current page. Bind the visibility of layout & check which page is on stack  & then hide rest which aren't needed